# How to get array in ascending order based on key value in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, dictionary, nsmutablearray

I am creating a database App in `Swift3`, where I have to display the data in `UITableView` from `JSON`. Below is my `JSON` :

```
{
    "Success": 1,
    "data": [{
        "Session_Details": [{
                "Start_Time": "08:00",
                "End_Time": "10:00",
                "Tag_Details": [{
                    "Tag_Id": 1,
                    "Tag_Name": "Test 1",
                    "Tag_Order": 4
                }]
            },
            {
                "Start_Time": "10:30",
                "End_Time": "12:30",
                "Tag_Details": [{
                    "Tag_Id": 2,
                    "Tag_Name": "Test 2",
                    "Tag_Order": 1
                }]
            },
            {
                "Start_Time": "10:30",
                "End_Time": "12:30",
                "Tag_Details": [{
                    "Tag_Id": 3,
                    "Tag_Name": "Test 3",
                    "Tag_Order": 3
                }]
            },
            {
                "Start_Time": "13:30",
                "End_Time": "15:20",
                "Tag_Details": [{
                    "Tag_Id": 1,
                    "Tag_Name": "Test 1",
                    "Tag_Order": 4
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I have already parsed the `JSON` and getting all the `JSON` data.

My problem is I have to create an array of 'Tag_Details' that should have unique value, It means `Tag_Id` should be unique. Also I have to set the array in `ascending` order based on `Tag_Order` key.

I am trying below code but not working :

```
var sessions : [SessionData]! {
        return AgendaDataManager.sharedInstance.sessionData
}

let sortedResults = session.tagDetails!.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "tagOrder", ascending: true)])

let sessionTag = ((session.tagDetails as AnyObject).allObjects as! [TagData])[0]
```

Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: You should make your life easier updating your Xcode to 10.1 / Swift 4.2.1, make use of Codable protocol, structure your data response and make it conform to Comparable protocol to be able to sort it accordingly

Comment: @LeoDabusThank you for your response, I am using CoreData here. Can you please suggest me here how can I resolve this?

Comment: You should edit your post and include your structures and how you decode your join data

Comment: Currently I don't have Structure, I was trying this at evening.

Comment: My Modal Class name is SessionData, that have Tag_Details also. Can you give me some roughly idea?

Comment: start with `struct Root {
    let success: Int
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum {
    let sessionDetails: [SessionDetail]
}

struct SessionDetail {
    let startTime: String
    let endTime: String
    let tagDetails: [TagDetail]
}

struct TagDetail {
    let tagId: Int
    let tagName: String
    let tagOrder: Int
}` and create custom initialisers that takes a dictionary as parameter for all structures

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188157/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: You question is too broad. You should provide a mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help us better assist you but I can see in your post that there is too many issues to list but I think I cover them all in my post below. good luck in your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding in Swift 3 and can't work with Codable protocol

First you should structure your json data. You can use this helper [quick type](https://app.quicktype.io) that will give a pretty good start point:

```
struct Root {
    let success: Bool
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum {
    let sessionDetails: [SessionDetail]
}

struct SessionDetail {
    let startTime: String
    let endTime: String
    let tagDetails: [TagDetail]
}

struct TagDetail {
    let tagId: Int
    let tagName: String
    let tagOrder: Int
}
```

---

Them you would need to create a custom initialiser for your root structure that takes a Data parameter (JSON Data):

```
typealias Dictionary = [String: Any]
typealias Dictionaries = [[String: Any]]

extension Root {
    init?(_ data: Data) {
        let dictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? Dictionary ?? [:]
        success = dictionary["Success"] as? Bool == true
        guard success else {
            return nil
        }
        self.data = (dictionary["data"] as! Dictionaries).map(Datum.init)
    }
}
```

---

And initialisers that takes a dictionary for all structures.

```
extension Datum {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        sessionDetails = (dictionary["Session_Details"] as! Dictionaries)
            .map(SessionDetail.init)
    }
}

extension SessionDetail {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        startTime = dictionary["Start_Time"] as! String
        endTime = dictionary["End_Time"] as! String
        tagDetails = (dictionary["Tag_Details"] as! Dictionaries).map(TagDetail.init)
    }
}

extension TagDetail: CustomStringConvertible {
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        tagId = dictionary["Tag_Id"] as! Int
        tagName = dictionary["Tag_Name"] as! String
        tagOrder = dictionary["Tag_Order"] as! Int
    }
    var description: String {
        return "TagDetail(Id: \(tagId) - Name: \(tagName) - Order: \(tagOrder))"
    }
}
```

Next you will need to make TagDetail conform to Equatable and Comparable:

```
extension TagDetail: Equatable, Comparable {
    static func == (lhs: TagDetail, rhs: TagDetail) -> Bool {
        return lhs.tagId == rhs.tagId
    }
    static func < (lhs: TagDetail, rhs: TagDetail) -> Bool {
        return lhs.tagOrder < rhs.tagOrder
    }
}
```

---

Once you accomplish all these steps you can easily filter and sort your objects:

---

```
let data = Data("""
{
"Success": 1,
"data": [{
"Session_Details": [{
"Start_Time": "08:00",
"End_Time": "10:00",
"Tag_Details": [{
"Tag_Id": 1,
"Tag_Name": "Test 1",
"Tag_Order": 4
}]
},
{
"Start_Time": "10:30",
"End_Time": "12:30",
"Tag_Details": [{
"Tag_Id": 2,
"Tag_Name": "Test 2",
"Tag_Order": 1
}]
},
{
"Start_Time": "10:30",
"End_Time": "12:30",
"Tag_Details": [{
"Tag_Id": 3,
"Tag_Name": "Test 3",
"Tag_Order": 3
}]
},
{
"Start_Time": "13:30",
"End_Time": "15:20",
"Tag_Details": [{
"Tag_Id": 1,
"Tag_Name": "Test 1",
"Tag_Order": 4
}]
}
]
}]
}
""".utf8)
```

---

```
if let root = Root(data), root.success,
    let sessionDetails = root.data.first?.sessionDetails {
    for detail in sessionDetails {
        print(detail)
    }
    let allTagDetails = sessionDetails.flatMap{$0.tagDetails}
    let tagDetailsSorted = allTagDetails.sorted()
    print("\n\n\n")
    var set = Set<Int>()
    let tagDetailsSortedSet = tagDetailsSorted.filter({ set.insert($0.tagId).inserted })
    tagDetailsSortedSet.map{print($0)}
}
```

This will print

> SessionDetail(startTime: "08:00", endTime: "10:00", tagDetails:
>   [TagDetail(Id: 1 - Name: Test 1 - Order: 4)])
>
> SessionDetail(startTime:
>   "10:30", endTime: "12:30", tagDetails: [TagDetail(Id: 2 - Name: Test 2
>   - Order: 1)])
>
> SessionDetail(startTime: "10:30", endTime: "12:30", tagDetails: [TagDetail(Id: 3 - Name: Test 3 - Order: 3)])
>
> SessionDetail(startTime: "13:30", endTime: "15:20", tagDetails:
>   [TagDetail(Id: 1 - Name: Test 1 - Order: 4)])

and

> TagDetail(Id: 2 - Name: Test 2 - Order: 1)
>
> TagDetail(Id: 3 - Name: Test 3 - Order: 3)
>
> TagDetail(Id: 1 - Name: Test 1 - Order: 4)